# R replication of Tableau dashboard actions

Tags: r, shiny, action, dashboard, flexdashboard

I am very new to R and programming but am getting there with the basics of flexdashboard and the basics of visualisation in R.
I currently produce visualisations in Tableau, in particular a dashboard which has a treemap at the top (with around 21 KPI's) which powers a trend chart below (for the relevant KPI) and also links through to a URL link to a tableau visualisation-this all works on a set of 'actions' within tableau.
Is this possible to replicate within R? (i.e. have 1 part of the visualisation 'action/trigger' the others to show the relevant visualisations?  From what I have seen so far I can only use navigation bars and filters to influence what the user sees (rather than have one visualisation power the others.  I can send a sample link of what I am trying to replicate if that helps? 
Id be very very grateful if anyone could advise?

Answer (score 0):

You that is possible. You could use:

- [DT for interactive tables, see section 2.](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html)
- [plotly_selected or plotly_click for interactive charts](https://plot.ly/r/shiny-coupled-events/)

You could then use [observeEvents](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/observeEvent.html) to listen to these actions, and make your application act accordingly.

Hope this helps you in the right direction.